# ESP8266 TCP connection WiFiClient issue

Tags: esp8266, wifi, tcpip

I am using ESP8266 01 board to send some data via TCP to server on local network. My code is:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "ssid";
const char* password = "pas";

const char* host = "192.168.1.103";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Wifi connection

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

   delay(5000);

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int port = 8888;
  if (!client.connect(host, port)) 
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

}

void loop() {

  while(Serial.available() == 0)
  {
    //wait for arduino serial data
  }

   while(Serial.available())
  {
    // send data to server
    client.print(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

After chacking code in Arduino IDE I am getting error message:

```
In function 'void loop()':
espwifitcp1:57: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope
     client.print(Serial.read());
     ^
exit status 1
'client' was not declared in this scope
```

It appears that if I declare `WiFiClient client;` inside `setup()` function it can't be accessed outside it. Do I correctly understand the problem? I have tried to declare object outside `setup()` and `loop()` functions but it got even more errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `WiFiClient client;` in the scope of setup() only. Move it's declaration to the global scope by placing it above the declaration of `void setup()`

Comment: Or write `WiFiClient` instead of `WifiClient` X_X

Answer (score -1):

in the header include WifiClient.h

Comment: ESP8266WiFi.h includes WiFiClient.h